# Moving object with mouse smoothly

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, game-physics, mousemove

I want my object to follow where my mouse is, like a point and click game. Problem is, while I can make my object move to where my mouse clicked, I can't make it do so smoothly. For example, I want to move my object from [point A to point B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhaAl.png). I can move it in a 45° angle until it has one of the same axis's as my mouse click, and then have it move straight towards the other axis [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQmpW.png). But I can't figure out how to make it move smooth, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9gaA.png).

I move my object with this:

```
private void Game_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsMouseDown == true)
    {
        _xClick = e.Location.X;
        _yClick = e.Location.Y;
        timerClickMovement.Enabled = true;
    }
}
private void Game_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    IsMouseDown = true;
}
private void Game_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    IsMouseDown = false;
}
private void timerClickMovement_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_x != _xClick || _y != _yClick)
    {
        //_x and _y is the location of the object I want to move.
        if (_x > _xClick)
        { _x--; }
        else if (_x < _xClick)
        { _x++; }
        if (_y > _yClick)
        { _y--; }
        else if (_y < _yClick)
        { _y++; }
        Invalidate();
    }
    else
    { timerClickMovement.Enabled = false; }
}
```

What can I do to make the movement more direct?

Comment: calculate the movement depending on the distance and the difference between x and y. and then don't move just by 1 pixel, move by your "difference level". e.g. if x and xtarget are 100px apart, and y and ytarget, move x 1px every tick, and y 2px every tick

Comment: You mean take the larger number and divide it by the smaller number to figure out how much Space I need to move the larger number each step? Because I've tried that, and I kept getting a divide by zero error, despite me putting in an if statement which would only do the calculation if neither of the variables had a 0 in them.

Comment: yeah like _xdistance = _xClick - x, same for y, then _xstepSize = _xdistance / _ydistance; then x+=_xStepSize instead of x++, shoud work, but not very elegant and only works if _xClick is higher than x

Answer (score 0):

To move an object in a game toward a specific direction, you can use the following pseudocode:

```
x_delta = cos(direction)*speed;
y_delta = sin(direction)*speed;

x_position+=x_delta;
y_position+=y_delta;
```

Where the total distance moved each step is determined by the float `speed`.

To travel toward a specific location, you can create a condition that prevents your object from moving faster than the final distance with something like:

```
if(mvtEnabled){
   float tempDst = object.dst(x_final, y_final);
   if(speed>tempDst){
      update(tempDst);
      mvtEnabled = false;
   }else{
      update(speed);
   }
}
```

Where `update` updates the positions based on the given speed. Each click, `mvtEnabled` is set to true and the final coordinates are recalculated.

You can get the angle between the starting location and the final location through something like this:

```
float direction = atan2(y_final - y_start, x_final - x_start);
```

and use this angle when you update your object's position.